# Resolve a generic controller that inherits a base controller and implements a specific class

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I'm trying resolve a generic controller that inherits a base controller and implements a specific class.
My wording an naming of "things" is not the best so I will just try to explain it in code.

```
public class BaseObject
{
}

public class TestObject : BaseObject
{
}

public class BaseController<T> : Controller
{
}

public class TestObjectController : BaseController<TestObject>
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new TestObject());
    }
}

 public static MvcHtmlString RenderObj<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{

    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    var baseObject = metaData.Model as BaseObject; //In this case baseObject is TestObject

    var type = baseObject.GetType();

    var assembly = type.Assembly;
    var t = assembly.GetTypes(); //Here I want to find TestObjectController<TestObject>
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Silvermind My TestObjectController's model can contain diffrent types of BaseObject and I want to execute corresponding controller and pass my object down to it and render it in my TestObjectController view.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to find the controller that  inherits the `BaseController<T>` where `T` is the model found by using ModelMetaData?

Comment: Can you not just say `if metaData is TestObject` use TestObjectController?

Comment: @Silvermind Exactly! ModelMetaData in this case is of the type of TestObject.

Comment: @landoncz Because there will be alot of controllers that inherits BaseController<T> and I don't want to hard code them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple console application which is not thouroughly tested, but should set you on the right track.
I leave the error checks and further filtering down up to you:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // obviously you already have this
    BaseObject obj = new TestObject();

    // you know this
    var myType = obj.GetType();

    // you know the type of the base class
    var baseControllerType = typeof(BaseController<>);

    // make the type generic using your model type
    baseControllerType = baseControllerType.MakeGenericType(myType);

    // the baseControllerType is now Generic BaseController<TestObject>

    // reference all types in a variable for a 'cleaner' linq query expression
    var allTypes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes();

    // get all types that are a sub class of BaseController<TestObject>
    var daController = (from type in allTypes
                        where type.IsSubclassOf(baseControllerType)
                        select type).FirstOrDefault();

    // optionally create an instance.
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(daController);

}

public class BaseObject
{
}

public class TestObject : BaseObject
{
}

public class BaseController<T>
{
}

public class TestObjectController : BaseController<TestObject>
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it tomorrow and report back :)

Comment: @TobiasLindberg Have you tried it? I am curious to know whether this is what you asked for ;).

Comment: Yes I have and Its exactly what i'm looking for :). Thanks!